# Can't Create Django Test Database

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-tests

I have a django 3.2/mysql 5.7.38 web site that is working. I am trying to write some unit test for the first time, and I am getting an error regarding the creation of the test database. About 1/2 of the tables are created before this error occurs (hence the question about the database already exists.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_hopi_django'; database exists")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_hopi_django', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_hopi_django.CurrentArticle' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 725, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 645, in setup_databases
    debug_sql=self.debug_sql, parallel=self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 183, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict['TEST'].get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 79, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 246, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 106, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 98, in add_field
    super().add_field(model, field)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 522, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_hopi_django.CurrentArticle' doesn't exist")
```

My settings.py has this for the db section:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'hopi_django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': 'hopi_django',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            # Tell MySQLdb to connect with 'utf8mb4' character set
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
        # Tell Django to build the test database with the 'utf8mb4' character set
        'TEST': {
            'CHARSET': 'utf8mb4',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'NAME': 'test_hopi_django',
        }
    }
}
```

The CurrentArticle model was imported from another MySQL database along with several other tables. I made some changes to the model after the import as noted in the comments. I changed the case of the field names, changed a field from ForeignKey to PostiveIntegerField, expanded the article_type options, and added a field. These are all reflected in the migrations for this table. This table and all the imported tables are working correctly.

```
class CurrentArticle(models.Model):
    
    # Field definitions for field_type
    NO_SOURCE = 0
    SPACE_PLACE = 1
    SOLAR_SYSTEM_NEWS = 2
    NIGH_SKY_NEWS = 3
    
    SOURCES = (
        (NO_SOURCE, 'No Source'),
        (SPACE_PLACE, 'Space Place'),
        (SOLAR_SYSTEM_NEWS, 'Solar System News'),
        (NIGH_SKY_NEWS, 'Night Sky News'),
    )
        
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    article_type = models.IntegerField(choices = SOURCES, default = NO_SOURCE)
    #article_id = models.ForeignKey(Articles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='articleID')
    article_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='articleID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    article_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='articleNumber')  # Field name made lowercase.
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(db_column='lastUpdate', auto_now=True, editable=False)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        #managed = False
        db_table = 'CurrentArticle'
```

The CurrentArticle table exists in the non-test database.

```
mysql> show columns in hopi_django.CurrentArticle;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| articleID     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| articleNumber | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| lastUpdate    | datetime         | NO   |     | 2022-01-01 09:00:00 |                |
| article_type  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

THere seems to be an issue in the migrations for this table based on the error messages, but I am not sure what is causing the error.

I also granted all privileges for the test_hopi_django and hopi_django databases to user hopi_django.

```
mysql> show grants for hopi_django@localhost;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for hopi_django@localhost                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'hopi_django'@'localhost'                           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hopi_django`.* TO 'hopi_django'@'localhost'      |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_hopi_django`.* TO 'hopi_django'@'localhost' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I re-ran the `./manage.py test` using the option `-v2` and got the following:

```
Destroying old test database for alias 'default' ('test_hopi_django')...
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs, django_nuages_tag, humanize, messages, staticfiles, widget_tweaks
  Apply all migrations: admin, articles, auth, contenttypes, flights, gallery, launchdate, old_gallery3, sessions, simulation, viewcount
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying flights.0001_initial... OK
  Applying articles.0001_initial... OK
  Applying articles.0002_alter_currentarticle_options... OK
  Applying articles.0003_auto_20220201_1856...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_hopi_django.CurrentArticle' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 725, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 645, in setup_databases
    debug_sql=self.debug_sql, parallel=self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 183, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict['TEST'].get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 79, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 246, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 106, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 98, in add_field
    super().add_field(model, field)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 522, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/new_hopirockets_website/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_hopi_django.CurrentArticle' doesn't exist")
```

These are the articles migrations. The error occurs in processing the third migration, but I don't see the issue.

```
**0001_initial.py **
# Generated by Django 3.2.11 on 2022-02-01 15:56

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('flights', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CurrentArticle',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('article_number', models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='articleNumber')),
                ('last_update', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_column='lastUpdate')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'CurrentArticle',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Articles',
            fields=[
                ('article_id', models.AutoField(db_column='articleID', primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('author', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('body', models.TextField()),
                ('intro', models.TextField()),
                ('caption', models.TextField()),
                ('credits', models.TextField()),
                ('article_date', models.DateField(db_column='articleDate')),
                ('image_title', models.CharField(db_column='imageTitle', max_length=255)),
                ('image_alt_text', models.CharField(db_column='imageAltText', max_length=255)),
                ('image_width', models.FloatField(db_column='imageWidth')),
                ('image_height', models.FloatField(db_column='imageHeight')),
                ('image_file', models.CharField(db_column='imageFile', max_length=255)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'Articles',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='StudentArticles',
            fields=[
                ('article_id', models.AutoField(db_column='articleID', primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('author', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('body', models.TextField()),
                ('article_type', models.CharField(db_column='articleType', max_length=255)),
                ('image_file', models.CharField(db_column='imageFile', max_length=255)),
                ('image_map', models.TextField(db_column='imageMap')),
                ('map_text', models.CharField(db_column='mapText', max_length=255)),
                ('article_date', models.DateField(db_column='articleDate')),
                ('image_width', models.CharField(db_column='imageWidth', max_length=255)),
                ('image_height', models.CharField(db_column='imageHeight', max_length=255)),
                ('image_alt_text', models.CharField(db_column='imageAltText', max_length=255)),
                ('flight_id', models.ForeignKey(db_column='flight_id', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='flights.flights')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'StudentArticles',
            },
        ),
    ]

**0002_alter_currentarticle_options.py**
#Generated by Django 3.2.11 on 2022-02-01 16:18

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('articles', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='currentarticle',
            options={},
        ),
    ]

**0003_auto_20220201_1856.py**
# Generated by Django 3.2.11 on 2022-02-02 01:56

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('articles', '0002_alter_currentarticle_options'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SolarSystemNewsArticles',
            fields=[
                ('article_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('image_alt_text', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('image_file', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'SolarSystemNewsArticles',
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='currentarticle',
            name='article_id',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column='articleID', default=1, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='articles.articles'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='currentarticle',
            name='article_type',
            field=models.IntegerField(choices=[(0, 'No Source'), (1, 'Space Place'), (2, 'Solar System News')], default=0),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='currentarticle',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: The error suggests some statement wanted that table to exist. Do you have any other tables that reference it with a foreign key, or any view or trigger or stored procedure that references it? The table must be created before those other things can reference it.

Comment: No ForeignKeys to this table. It is referenced in a view, the migrations for this table, and admin.py. But so are all the other imported and not imported tables that are created before this error occurs. I don't have any triggers or stored procedures.

Comment: Please run the tests with the `-v2` option (something like `./manage.py test -v2`). This should help identify which migration causes the problem.

Comment: Also, can you verify that there exists a migration that creates the `CurrentArticle` table?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides - thanks for the -v2 option; it was very helpful. The 0001_init.py migration creates the CurrentArticle table. I edited the original post to include the migrations leading up to the error, and I still don't see the cause of the problem. The failure occurs on the third migration.

Comment: @user1045680 the 0001_init.py migration does not create the CurrentArticle table because it includes the option `managed=False`, try just removing that from the migration to create the table

Comment: @IainShelvington that did the trick! Thanks for catching it!